# Parsing RSS, maybe php4->php5 issue?

Tags: php, xml, rss, feed

long time listener first time caller...

I have this function (I don;t recall where its from sorry, I've had it forever)

It simply parses an XML feed and creates a list of upcoming gigs - it was working fine but changing to a new server with latest PHP and it isn't working.

```
    function parseRSS($url) { 

    $feedeed = implode('', file($url));
    $parser = xml_parser_create();
    xml_parse_into_struct($parser, $feedeed, $valueals, $index);
    xml_parser_free($parser);

    foreach($valueals as $keyey => $valueal){
        if($valueal['type'] != 'cdata') {
            $item[$keyey] = $valueal;
        }
    }
    $i = 0;
    foreach($item as $key => $value){
        if($value['type'] == 'open') {
            $i++;
            $itemame[$i] = $value['tag']; 
        } elseif($value['type'] == 'close') {

            $feed = $values[$i];
            $item = $itemame[$i];
            $i--;

            if(count($values[$i])>1){
                $values[$i][$item][] = $feed;
            } else {
                $values[$i][$item] = $feed;
            }
        } else {
            $values[$i][$value['tag']] = $value['value'];  
        }
    }
    return $values[0];
} 

$xml = parseRSS("http://acousti.co/feeds/artist/AboveThem");

$count = 0;

foreach($xml['RSS']['CHANNEL']['ITEM'] as $item) {
        $pubDate = $item['PUBDATE'];
        $pubDateFormatted = date('D j M Y', strtotime($pubDate));

        echo("<a href=\"{$item['LINK']}\" target=\"_blank\" class=\"indexBoxNews\">{$item['DESCRIPTION']}{$link}</a>
            <p class=\"rss-date\">$pubDateFormatted</p>");

        if (++$count == 5) break;
}
```

Does anyone know why it may have stopped working - the code was written pre-PHP5 that's for sure so maybe it's a compatibility issue?

Any help very much appreciated :)
Rob

Comment: omg are there still hosting companies offering php 4? this is a frightening development.

Comment: Do you get any warnings? Enable `error_reporting(E_ALL);` atop the script. And/or show us a `print_r($valueals);` after `xml_parse_into_struct` example.

Comment: Thanks. No errors at all and putting the print_r in gives an empty array. http://abovethem.net/test/abovethem_xml.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're now on PHP 5, you may want to just rewrite the code using simplexml. PHP4, without adding additional libraries, didn't have a good easy way of dealing with XML, but now with PHP 5, your code should be a fraction of what you used for PHP 4.

Try this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://acousti.co/feeds/artist/AboveThem');

foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item)
{
    $pubDateFormatted = date('D j M Y', strtotime((string) $item->pubDate));
    echo '<a href="' . (string) $item->link . '" target="_blank" class="indexBoxNews">' . (string) $item->description . '</a>
            <p class="rss-date">' . $pubDateFormatted . '</p>';
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks Francis, that code works great locally but still not working on live - how strange? Looks like it's not the code that's the problem after all (however I won't be going back to the old version :)

Any tests I can do? I've tried var_dump on $xml (false) but I'm stuck at what I can do after that.

Comment: Hmm, check to make sure the PHP you're using is compiled with XML.
The XML you had previously should have worked on PHP 5 if it was compiled with XML support.
If you create a new page on your server and put `<?php phpinfo();` then browse to that page and search for XML - see if it's listed on the page. If it's not listed, you'll probably want to ask your host to compile PHP with XML (it's a very critical component) or change hosts (kind of a pain, but it would be stupid for a host to not have PHP compiled with XML).
Delete the phpinfo page from your server when you're done looking at it.

Comment: Also, make sure allow_url_fopen is on. In another page, you can do this: `echo ini_get('allow_url_fopen');` If it results to false, you may be able to turn it on via .htaccess, if not, another thing to ask your host about.

Comment: Thanks Francis, I've messaged the server guys - hopefully they'll be able to sort it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that PHP's "allow_url_fopen" ini setting is set to true on the new server, otherwise the file($url) won't work

http://gr.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen

Comment: Great - checked phpinfo and it's off. Time to contact support and get that sorted, I hope they can sort.

Comment: Thanks again all - Hoping this works and I'll be back when it's up and running.